# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib with importing syft in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pysyft

I create a new environment (my_syft env) with conda and python 3.9.7 and install syft 0.5.0.

Then I check the installation of my module and it's seem that the installations pass correctly

```
C:\Users\tamir>conda activate my_syft_env
        
(my_syft_env) C:\Users\tamir>python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on 
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import syft
>>>
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\envs\my_syft_env\python.exe
>>>
```

Then in try to run and check my module in VScode and choose the current environment  C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\envs\my_syft_env\python.exe

```
import syft
print("hellow")
```

but get en error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tamir\Desktop\TAMIR\pyton vscode\federated.py", line 1, in <module>
    import syft
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from syft.core.node.device.device import Device  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\core\node\device\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .client import DeviceClient
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\core\node\device\client.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..common.client import Client
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\core\node\common\client.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ....lib import create_lib_ast
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\lib\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..lib.torch import create_torch_ast
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\lib\torch\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import parameter  # noqa: 401
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\lib\torch\parameter.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ...lib.torch.tensor_util import tensor_deserializer
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\syft\lib\torch\tensor_util.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyarrow as pa
  File "C:\Users\tamir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    import pyarrow.lib as _lib
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I dont know why there is an error.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing syft or pyarrow? `pip install syft --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

I may be late, but to paraphrase [this thread](https://github.com/conda-forge/pyarrow-feedstock/issues/54), you might have installed `libboost` and `boost-cpp` from the default conda channels. Try the following:

- `conda install libboost boost-cpp -c conda-forge`
- If on a Windows machine, make sure you have Visual C++ Redistributables 2019 or later.
- See if the pip version of pyarrow works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, on windows with python 3.10, and which I solved as follows:

1. upgrade pip:

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

2. install/upgrade `pyarrow`:

> pip install --upgrade pyarrow